# Individual "Custom Scaling" per monitor in Windows 10 (1809)?

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, scaling

I am a happy Windows 10 user. Now I got a new 13 inch laptop that has a 1920 x 1080 resolution and the pixels are tiny. I could even live with those tiny pixels if I would not be using it with an external 27 inch monitor that also has a 1920 x 1080 resolution (with gigantic pixels, in comparison).

Windows 10 of course has the option to change the size of the UI on each screen, unfortunately it offers only 25% steps:

[image: Scale and layout on Windows 10: 100%, 125%, 150%, 175%]

While 100% is too small, 125% is already too large to be comfortable on the laptop.

In theory there is also a "Custom Scaling" option in Windows 10 (behind the "Advanced scaling settings" link below the dropdown) that lets you enter any value between 100 and 500 for scaling:

[image: Custom scaling: 100-500, all your displays will be set to the scaling oyu enter]

But the highlighted sentence tells me that "all displays will be set to the custom scaling size" (and manual testing confirms this) - so there doesn't seem to be a way to set custom scaling for individual screens.

Am I missing something here or can I *either* use the 100/125/150 steps for each individual screen *or* the identical custom scaling (100,101,102,103,...) for all screens?

---

Windows version info:

[image: Windows 10 Pro, 1809, 17763.348]

Comment: In *Settings > System > Display*, don't you see the two monitors? In theory, clicking on one lets you set its separate scaling.

Comment: Yes, but only the 100/125/150 scaling. As I need e.g. 110, I have to click "Advanced scaling settings" to get to the custom scaling which I can only apply to both monitors at the same time.

Comment: Finer adjustments are available in *Settings  > Ease of Access > Display* using a slider. I can't check how this works for multiple monitors.

Comment: Thanks, but I see only "Make text bigger" with a slider (which applies to all screens and really just increases text, not UI), "Make everything bigger" with the same 100/125/150/175 steps and a "Change the size of apps on other displays" which goes to the normal "Display" settings :(

Comment: depending on what graphics you have, you could also use Intel Graphics Settings in which you might be able to set custom scaling by selecting another display.

Comment: What is the computer model, the display adapter and the monitor.

Comment: Lenovo Thinkbook 13s, Intel UHD Graphics 620, BenQ GL2760

Comment: Using Intel Graphics Settings I can indeed set a custom resolution for the laptop screen, seems by doing some math manually I might be able to get it to a resolution that would match 110 scale. Let's see if this works.